# Linking problems with c++ on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, linker-errors

my problem is, that I want to compile some c++ code on OS X. On Linux this worked just fine, but if I want to compile it on mac I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test2::printHelloWorld()", referenced from:
      test::printHelloWorld() in test.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have three little files, that depend on each other and a CMAKE:

```
//main.cpp
#include "test.h"

int main() {
  test t;
  t.printHelloWorld(); //<- this calls printHelloWorld from test.h
  return 0;
}
```

```
//test.h
class test {
 public:
  void printHelloWorld(); //<- this calls printHelloWorld from test2.h
};
```

```
//test.cpp
#include test2.h

test::printHelloWorld(){
  test2 t;
  t.printHelloWorld();
}
```

```
//test2.h
class test2 {
 public:
  void printHelloWorld();
};
```

```
//test2.cpp
#include <iostream>

test2::printHelloWorld(){
  std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

```
//CMAKE
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_library(lib2 SHARED test2.cpp)
add_library(lib SHARED test.cpp)
add_executable(Test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Test lib)
target_link_libraries(Test lib2)
```

As I said, building this on Linux with gcc works fine, but building this on OS X generates the error.

I tried the following:

- Building with g++ on OS X
- Using "libc++" flag
- building without CLion

My environment:

- OSX 10.15.7
- CLION 2020.2.4

I am sorry if this is a really dump question. I tried to google this for two days now and I can't find any answer.

I know that I could just change my cmake `target_link_libraries(Test lib2) -> target_link_libraries(lib lib2)`, but I want to know why this is working on Linux and not on OS X.

Edit: added .cpp sources and includes

Comment: Did you try to compile your code in a terminal emulator as a command line? Read documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Comment: Does your main.cpp includes test.h?

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. @Basile: I tried build it in my terminal with cmake and make. Is this, what you meant?

Comment: @adembudak: Yes it is. I included test.h in my main.cpp and test2.h in my test.h

Answer (score 0):

If test2 depends on test and should not be visible, adjust your CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(Test PUBLIC lib)
target_link_libraries(lib PRIVATE lib2)
```

Compiling with `cmake -G Ninja . && ninja && ./Test` runs fine on macOS 10.15.7.

Comment: Hi Macintron, know that I can just my cmake. But this example, that I am providing is only an example. In my case I have about 60.000 loc that I want to compile on Mac and to fix all library's would need a lot of time. I want to know, why this is compiling on linux, but not on Mac.

Comment: From my perspective, macOS works correctly, because lib uses symbols from lib2 and in your CMakeLists.txt there is no connection between lib and lib2.

Comment: I agree with you. But I think its weird that cmake/make/clang on Mac is behaving so different compared to cmake/make/gcc on linux :)

Comment: clang and gcc fail on the Mac. Tests on Linux with clang/gcc are linking fine.